# Why do columns change to nullable in Apache Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Why is `nullable = true` used after some functions are executed even though there are no NaN values in the `DataFrame`.

```scala
val myDf = Seq((2,"A"),(2,"B"),(1,"C"))
         .toDF("foo","bar")
         .withColumn("foo", 'foo.cast("Int"))

myDf.withColumn("foo_2", when($"foo" === 2 , 1).otherwise(0)).select("foo", "foo_2").show
```

When `df.printSchema` is called now `nullable` will be `false` for both columns.

```scala
val foo: (Int => String) = (t: Int) => {
    fooMap.get(t) match {
      case Some(tt) => tt
      case None => "notFound"
    }
  }

val fooMap = Map(
    1 -> "small",
    2 -> "big"
 )
val fooUDF = udf(foo)

myDf
    .withColumn("foo", fooUDF(col("foo")))
    .withColumn("foo_2", when($"foo" === 2 , 1).otherwise(0)).select("foo", "foo_2")
    .select("foo", "foo_2")
    .printSchema
```

However now, `nullable` is `true` for at least one column which was `false` before. How can this be explained?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When creating `Dataset` from statically typed structure (without depending on `schema` argument) Spark uses a relatively simple set of rules to determine `nullable` property.

- If object of the given type can be `null` then its `DataFrame` representation is `nullable`.
- If object is an `Option[_]` then then its `DataFrame` representation is `nullable` with `None` considered to be SQL `NULL`.
- In any other case it will be marked as not `nullable`.

Since Scala `String` is `java.lang.String`, which can be `null`, generated column can is `nullable`. For the same reason `bar` column is `nullable` in the initial dataset:

```scala
val data1 = Seq[(Int, String)]((2, "A"), (2, "B"), (1, "C"))
val df1 = data1.toDF("foo", "bar")
df1.schema("bar").nullable
```

```
Boolean = true
```

but `foo` is not (`scala.Int` cannot be `null`).

```scala
df1.schema("foo").nullable
```

```
Boolean = false
```

If we change data definition to:

```scala
val data2 = Seq[(Integer, String)]((2, "A"), (2, "B"), (1, "C"))
```

`foo` will be `nullable` (`Integer` is `java.lang.Integer` and boxed integer can be `null`):

```scala
data2.toDF("foo", "bar").schema("foo").nullable
```

```
Boolean = true
```

See also: [SPARK-20668](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20668) *Modify ScalaUDF to handle nullability*.

Comment: Best answer I've seen on this subject.

Answer (score 3):

You could change schema of dataframe very quickly as well. something like this would do the job -

```
def setNullableStateForAllColumns( df: DataFrame, columnMap: Map[String, Boolean]) : DataFrame = {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField, StructType}
    // get schema
    val schema = df.schema
    val newSchema = StructType(schema.map {
    case StructField( c, d, n, m) =>
      StructField( c, d, columnMap.getOrElse(c, default = n), m)
    })
    // apply new schema
    df.sqlContext.createDataFrame( df.rdd, newSchema )
}
```