# Why does Spark SQL turn nullable on for string column even when all values specified?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

So for something like this:

```
case class RandomClass(stringOne: String, stringTwo: String, numericOne: Int)
val ds = Seq(
  RandomClass("a", null, 1),  
  RandomClass("a", "x", 3), 
  RandomClass("a", "y", 4), 
  RandomClass("a", null, 5)
).toDS()

ds.printSchema()
```

results in

```
root
 |-- stringOne: string (nullable = true)
 |-- stringTwo: string (nullable = true)
 |-- numericOne: integer (nullable = false)
```

why would `stringOne` be `nullable?` Strangely, `numericOne` is inferred correctly. I assume I am just missing something about the relationship between Dataset and DataFrame API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why would `stringOne` be nullable

Because Scala `String` is just a Java String and unlike Scala `Int` can be `null`. Actual content (presence of `null` values or lack of it) simply doesn't matter.

See also [spark why do columns change to nullable true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40603756/6910411)

Answer (score 1):

It is true that Spark makes a best guess on nullability depending on whether the inferred type lies on the `AnyRef` or `AnyVal` side of the Scala object hierarchy, but note also that it can be more complicated than that. For example, when working with Parquet files, *everything* is inferred to be `nullable` for compatibility purposes.

Meanwhile, when you create a schema, you can simply set `nullable = true` everywhere if you like:

```
StructField(fieldName, LongType, nullable = true)

// or using a "DSL"
$"fieldName".long.copy(nullable = false)
```